# Permutation of $h$ cards drawn from a deck of $n$ cards made up of $r$ types

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

$h$ cards are drawn from a deck of $n$ cards, made up of $r$ types: $n_1$ cards of the $1^{st}$ type, $n_2$ cards of the $2^{nd}$ type, ..., $n_r$ cards of the $r^{th}$ type.

Reasoning,

- if $h = 1$ then the possible hands (**permutations of $h=1$ card drawn from $n$ cards**) are: $r$ ;
- if $h = n$ then the possible hands (**permutations of $h=n$ card drawn from $n$ cards**) are: $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!\cdots n_r!}= \prod_{i=1}^{r} \frac{n!}{n_i!}$ ;
- if $r=n$ (that means $n_1=n_2=...=n_r=1$) then the possible hands (**permutations of $h$ card drawn from $n=r$ cards**) are: $\frac{n!}{(n-h)!}$ .

(Post Scriptum: always taking into account duplicates)

**How do you calculate the permutations of $h$ cards drawn from n cards (consisting of r types, where the type $i^{th}$ is present in $n_i$ copies) when $1 ≤h ≤n$?** The answer, of course, must be correct for the extreme cases where $h=1$ and $h=n$.

I would like an answer with proof. If there is an answer that requires the use of generative functions, $\color{red}{\text{I ask you to explain it step by step}}$.

Reasoning a bit I think the answer could be similar to  $\frac{n!}{(n-h)!} \frac{1}{n_1!n_2!n_3!\cdots n_r!}= \prod_{i=1}^{r} \frac{n!}{(n-h)!} \frac{1}{n_i!}$ , beasuse it converges to the last two cases discussed if $h=n$ of if $r=n$, but is incorrect for the first case.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get a (not "simple") general expression is the following.

Let $r_k$ be the number of types of cards such that their number is greater or equal than $k$, i.e.:

$$r_k = |\{j: 1 \le j \le r \land n_j \ge k\}|$$

We have that $r_1 = r$.

Given $h$, we can compute the number of wanted permutations for one solution of the equation:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{ki_k}=h \tag{1}\label{1}$$

where $i_k$ is the number of distinct types of cards appearing each exactly $k$ times in the draw.

Starting from $k=n$, there are ${r_n \choose i_n}$ ways of choosing the $i_n$ types of cards. Then, for $k=n-1$ there are ${r_{n-1}-i_n \choose i_{n-1}}$ ways of choosing the $i_{n-1}$ types of cards, and in general ${r_k-\sum_{m=k+1}^{n}{i_m} \choose i_k}$ ways of choosing the $i_k$ types of cards.

Starting from $k=1$, the number of ways to choose $i_1$ distinct cards among the $h$ drawn is:

$${h \choose 1}{h-1 \choose 1}\ldots{h-i_1+1 \choose 1}=\frac{h!}{(h-i_1)!} \tag{2}$$

For $k=2$ we are left with $h-i_1$ cards for choosing $i_2$ couples of distinct types in the following number of ways:

$${h-i_1 \choose 2}{h-i_1-2 \choose 2}{h-i_1-4 \choose 2}\ldots{h-i_1-2(i_2-1) \choose 2} \tag{3}$$

and so on, giving the following total:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\biggl[{r_k-\sum_{m=k+1}^{n}{i_m} \choose i_k}\prod_{j=0}^{i_k-1}{{h-\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}{mi_m}-kj} \choose k}\biggr] \tag{4}$$

where we can express a factor as a multinomial coefficient:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{j=0}^{i_k-1}{{h-\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}{mi_m}-kj} \choose k}={h \choose h_1,h_2,\ldots,h_s} \tag{5}$$

where $s=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{i_k}$ and $h_1=h_2=\ldots=h_{i_1}=1$, $h_{i_1+1}=h_{i_1+2}=\ldots=h_{i_1+i_2}=2$, $h_{i_1+i_2+1}=h_{i_1+i_2+2}=\ldots=h_{i_1+i_2+i_3}=3$, and so on.

And summing over all solutions of \eqref{1} we get the final result:

$$\sum_{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{ki_k}=h}\;\prod_{k=1}^{n}\biggl[{r_k-\sum_{m=k+1}^{n}{i_m} \choose i_k}\prod_{j=0}^{i_k-1}{{h-\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}{mi_m}-kj} \choose k}\biggr] \tag{6}$$

Note that we can sum over all solutions because when $0 \le r_k-\sum_{m=k+1}^{n}{i_m} \lt i_k$ the binomial coefficient ${r_k-\sum_{m=k+1}^{n}{i_m} \choose i_k}$ evaluates to $0$. If instead $r_k-\sum_{m=k+1}^{n}{i_m} \lt 0$ then, since $r_{k+1} \le r_k$, we will have $r_{k+1}-\sum_{m=k+2}^{n}{i_m}-i_{k+1} \le r_k-\sum_{m=k+1}^{n}{i_m} \lt 0$ and therefore $r_{k+1}-\sum_{m=k+2}^{n}{i_m} \lt i_{k+1}$. Now, if $0 \le r_{k+1}-\sum_{m=k+2}^{n}{i_m}$ we are done, because the corresponding binomial coefficient evaluates to $0$, otherwise we continue to go up till we have $0 \le r_n \lt i_n$ and ${r_n \choose i_n} = 0$.

When $h=1$ the multinomial coefficient simplifies to $1$, we have the only solution $i_1=1$, $i_2=i_3=\ldots=i_n=0$ to \eqref{1}, and therefore the solution is $r_1=r$ as expected.

When $r=n$ we have $r_1=n$, the only solution $i_1=h$, $i_2=i_3=\ldots=i_n=0$ to \eqref{1}, and the multinomial coefficient evaluates to $h!$, therefore the solution is ${n \choose h}h!=\frac{n!}{(n-h)!}$ as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And to calculate the possible combinations of h cards (as before, drawn from a deck of n cards, consisting of r types)?  Are small changes enough? Could you tell me how it could be done step by step?

Comment: For combinations you simply remove the multinomial coefficient and remain with the sum of products of ${r_k \choose i_k}$.

Comment: You mean like this? $\sum_{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{ki_k}=h}\;\prod_{k=1}^{n}{r_k \choose i_k}$ The steps before should also be more simplified. Could you indicate them fully, please? I wouldn't want to make mistakes.

Comment: Yes like that. The multinomial coefficient is for the order, so the combinations don't have it. If this is homework, you should try to verify all steps yourself and make sure there is no error. For example, you can try some numeric examples or write a program for verification.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I have corrected a mistake: ${r_k \choose i_k}$ must be replaced with ${r_k-\sum_{m=k+1}^{n}{i_m} \choose i_k}$.